# Debugging and trying to step through visual studio project but buttons greyed out

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

So, I have used step in / step over debugging in smaller projects, but I have tried to use it in a larger project and the buttons are greyed out.  I have searched around on stackoverflow and google and nothing I found has been able to fix it.  Any ideas on what I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Add A Breakpoint
- Right Click the Breakpoint text
- Select "Run to Cursor"

Now you can run your program how you normally would, and when it hits that breakpoint, you will be able to step-into/step-over.